# Which video format should I use to render out 2d animation

Tags: rendering, animation, video, 2d

Ok so I'm trying to make 2d animation, but when it comes to rendering I don't know what format should I use, it will be no longer than 5 minutes and probably will be distributed online let's say it will be youtube, resolution is 1920x1080, fps will probably be 25, but maybe it'll be lower. 
So what format should I choose to get good looking colors and shapes that don't weights too much? 
Is any detailed guide on this topic? Oh and yes it will contain music/sound. 
P.S. yes i know about first rendering every frame as .png as I can pause rendering at any time and I don't have to go from start in case of crushing, I'll pass that since it may weight too much.

Comment: You should consult with whoever is going to host your video. For example here is a link to YouTubes video format guidelines https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en

Comment: @Dontwalk well this is only saying that they support variety of video formats, and that you cant upload project file it has to be rendered, well I get that. Thing is I don't know differences between formats and which one should I use for Good quality and that it doesn't weights too much, also i won't to choose format which is overkill for 2d animation

Comment: As it stands this question is both opinion based and about video codecs, non of which is on topic here. In theory no codec provides "better quality over others", what might happen is you get a bigger file size for equivalent quality, but there are just way too many variables to give you concise response. Want quality go with lossless compression, which is probably overkill, otherwise why not stick with the "standard" MP4 H264, I'm sure it will be enough unless you have some special needs.

Comment: Have you thouroughly read Dontwalks linked page? Literally the only link on it shows youtube's recommended [encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171), all of which can be set in Blender

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In other words I could slap any video format that host supports and I'll be fine no need to pick any special?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between them, not even side by side

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Well I tought it was kind of important, guess I'm wrong. If you want you can form this into answer and add some article about differences in formats. Thanks